# R dplyr cumsum per group

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I am trying to get the cumulative sum per group on a data set with dplyr using

```
iris %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    mutate(cum_sep_len = cumsum(Sepal.Length))
```

However, the sum is not actually done by groups, it's only the cumulative sum of all species. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: your code seems to work fine for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick plot of your data showing that the value of cum_sep_len does, in fact, start back at `0` for each `Species`.

```
cumsum_data <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(cum_sep_len = cumsum(Sepal.Length))

cumsum_data %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = row, y = cum_sep_len, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! The issue was that I accidentally uploaded plyr before dplyr.